# Best way convert number to string javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to convert a number to string in javascript?
I am familiar with these four possibilities:

**Example 1:**

```
let number = 2;
let string1 = String(number);
```

**Example 2**

```
let number = 2;
let string2 = number.toString();
```

**Example 3**

```
let number = 2;
let string3 = "" + number;
```

**Example 4**

```
let number = 2;
let string4 = number + "";
```

All examples giving the same result, but what is the best option to choose based on Performance? Or is it personal preference?

Thanks for answering.

Comment: "Best" regarding what? Readability? Performance?

Comment: Another one: let number = 2; let string = \`${number}\`

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to ask which option would be “the best”, if you do not specify _any_ criteria for what that classification should be based on.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with approach #2 is that it doesn’t work if the value is null or undefined.

1st , 3rd and 4th  which are basically equivalent.
""+value: The plus operator is fine for converting a value when it is surrounded by non-empty strings. As a way for converting a value to string, I find it less descriptive of one’s intentions. But that is a matter of taste, some people prefer this approach to String(value).
String(value): This approach is nicely explicit: Apply the function String() to value. The only problem is that this function call will confuse some people, especially those coming from Java, because String is also a constructor.

Comment: If it's null or undefined, then it's not a number in the first place, is it?

Comment: yes now you have hardcoaded , what if you are receiving it dynamicaly or getting from some other source.

Comment: Then I would *hope* that you perform `if( typeof input !== "number") throw new TypeError("input is not a number!");`

Comment: sure we can, but if we consider only this question, so i suggest the answers :)

Comment: If you receive it from other source you can simply **var num=Number(input);** to ensure you are dealing with a number, then format it back with **num.toString();**